# Disk Automorphism and Convergence of Zero

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, analysis, automorphism-group

It is understood that for the sequence of disk automorphisms
$$\frac{z-a_n}{1-\bar{a}_nz},$$
if $a_n\to a\in D_1$, then this sequence converges uniformly on compact subsets of $D_1$ to the automorphism
$$\frac{z-a}{1-\bar{a}z}.$$
I was wondering what we might be able to say about the converse of this statement? Namely, if
$$\frac{z-a_n}{1-\bar{a}_nz}\to \frac{z-a}{1-\bar{a}z}$$
on compact subsets of $D_1$, is it necessarily true that $a_n\to a\in D_1$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the functions $f_n(z) = \frac{z-a_n}{1-\bar{a}_nz}$ converge to $f(z) = \frac{z-a}{1-\bar{a}z}$ in the unit disk then
$$
 -a_n = f_n(0) \to f(0) = -a
$$
so that necessarily $a_n \to a$.